# How do I save multiple user settings in runtime in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am trying to make my app stay the way I left it after closing the app. Therefore I want to save set of items from ListView to the settings and I can't figure out how to do that. I've found some solutions but I believe they are outdated as they don't seem to work.

Image shows set of items in ListView which I want to save so they appear there after restarting the app:

[Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSLbD.png)

This is where I want them to appear:

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sN4w.png)

And this is part of code that I've tried out so far

```
 private void btn_SaveConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Settings.Default["IP"] = tBox_discoverServerFrom.Text;
        Settings.Default["DiscoveredServers"] = cBox_discoveredServers.Text;
        foreach (var item in lV_groups.Items)
        {
            var property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("Group"+i);
            property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
            property.Name = "Group " + i;
            Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
            Settings.Default.Save();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think using the Settings API is a great idea if you want to save any significant amount of data.

I would recommend the following

1. Create a class describing all the data you want to save. To make serialization easier it should have a parameter less constructor and public setters for all properties. This is sometimes called a Data-Transfer-Object (DTO)
2. Use [json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize the object to a file. You would normally place the file in a subfolder in the local app data folder: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`.
3. Do the reverse when you start the application. If there is a file, use Json to deserialize it and use it however you want.
4. You may optionally add logic to save the file periodically, this would allow recovery in case of application crashes. You might also want some system to keep more than one file, in case the application or computer crashes in the middle of a save operation, and the file becomes corrupt.

Comment: Thank you! Do you maybe know of some kind of example of this with ListViews?

Comment: @Tenki it will depend on your object model. There is no automatic functions for this. It is also usually recommended to use a MVVM / MVP / MVC scheme to separate your model from your UI. So ideally your serialization/storage layer would not be in any way dependent on the UI.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try it out. I have one last question. As you may see from the first image I have another ListView below the groups one which I use for items. Items are placed inside the group of choice. So for example I might have string, int, double items in Group0 and bool, int, float items in Group1. Do I have to do serialization separately for each ListView or may I make object of items inside the group object somehow and serialize them together that way.

Comment: @Tenki The serialization/DTO-object can contain arbitrary objects and nesting levels, as long as all of the objects are serializable. So you can serialize both groups, and any other data you might want to save in one go.